# cors post laravel vuejs (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: cors

People let me ask the same post method as to why the place is not. I'm calling api post between laravel and vuejs. thanks all read the article!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

looking at the first image, a script from `test.devpro.vn` is calling a script from `demo.devpro.vn`

this is considered [Cross origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), and the browser will check if the destination host has `access-control-allow-origin` flag enabled before it tries to get send the request.

access-control-allow-origin can be enabled on the destination server based on its type, if these these are both aliases to your testing environment, and you can just call scripts from the same host to work around the problem